# Using same domain name for Firebase Dynamic Link and Wix website

Tags: firebase-dynamic-links, velo

I already have a website in Wix that uses a domain that I owned (e.g [www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com)). At the same time, I wanted to use Firebase Dynamic Link. Is it possible for me to continue to host my website in Wix using the domain and use Firebase Dynamic Link that is set up to the same domain (using [www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com) for Firebase Dynamic Link)?

Comment: I would also like to know the answer to this...

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue with you. I need use firebase dynamic link to my app or website. But I can't move my website A record to firebase since I still need wix services. So I created a subdomain in my wix a record, and point that a record value to firebase host, either with A host or txt, after a few hours, I am able to use it from firebase. Just remember don't change your original WIX A record. Then you should be able to use subdomain.abc.com as dynamic link, also not mess up with original wix service.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31304974)